# VBA Excel: dynamically created button in a class module runs immediately and only once

Tags: vba, class, excel

I am trying to make class that would create a button. The button should have a macro assigned to it. The macro is a function of the class.

The code of the class module is the following:

```
'Class Module: btnClass
Option Explicit

Dim btn As Button

Function addButton()
    'Adding a button
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add( _
        Range("A1").Left, _
        Range("A1").Top, _
        Range("A1").Width, _
        Range("A1").Height)
    With btn
        'Assigning a function
        .OnAction = Me.onClickAction
        .Caption = "Button"
    End With
End Function

Function onClickAction()
    MsgBox ("Click")
End Function
```

The code of the main macro is the following:

```
'Module
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim btnInstance As btnClass
    Set btnInstance = New btnClass

    'Calling a function of the instance that creates a button
    Call btnInstance.addButton
End Sub
```

The code above creates a button successfully. However, the function assigned to the button is run immediately (right after the button is created, not when I click on it), and only once (when you click on the button later, nothing happens).

Is there a way in VBA to implement the required functionality using class modules (want to create a class that does not rely on the outside functions)?

Comment: The macro that the button should execute cannot be reached because it is inside the class module. Place this macro in the main (normal) module and see if that works for you. Otherwise you will probably have to declare the instance of the class as a global variable and use withevents like mielk shows, even though that will need some more tweaking.

Comment: Placing everything in the main (normal) module makes the code work. The problem is that this is a simple illustration example. In reality, I need to access variables stored in the instance of the class. If there is a way to pass that instance as a parameter of the function that is being called when the button is pressed, then it would be an acceptable solution. However, a quick googling says that there is no simple way to do that. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You only need to put the macro that needs to be started by the button in the normal module. You can then create a new instance of the class module in this macro and do all the work in the class module itself.

Comment: Is there a simple way to access the old instance (the one that actually called the function) in the normal module? Because in the end, what I would like to do is to manipulate the data stored in the variables of the instance, when the button is pressed.

Comment: The problem is that you would need to give control of the worksheet that the button is located on back to the user and this will mean that the vba code needs to be stopped. This means that all the information that was stored in memory for vba is no longer available. Having code run in the background, while control of the worksheet is given to the user, is hard to accomplish.

Comment: You'd have to use an ActiveX commandbutton, declare the variable `WithEvents` and have the class respond to its `Click` event. The native form buttons don't expose events you can use in this way. You could also use a public variable set to the instance of the class and have the form button's macro refer to that. Ugly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Rory's comment, your class needs something like this:

```
Public WithEvents Button As CommandButton

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Me.Button = Sheet1.OLEObjects("Thebutton").Object
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click()
    MsgBox "Foo"
End Sub
```

Then in a normal module create a public instance of the class so it stays in memmory:

```
Public myButt As ButtonClass

Public Sub AddEvent()
    Set myButt = New ButtonClass
End Sub
```

Note that the click event will only be handled as long as the instance of the class remains in memory. If you close the workbook and open it again the event will no longer be handled.

Edit: I forgot to mention, you need to set a reference to Microsoft Forms in order to declare a variable of type CommandButton.